# Trying to loop through worksheets and format specific tables in them

Tags: excel, vba, loops, worksheet

Instead of coding for every specific worksheet to format specific tables, I want to create a loop that formats only the tables in the list, on different worksheets.

current code: (sh and wbTemplate defined and set earlier in the code)

```
Dim AllTableNames As String
Dim TableNames As Variant
Dim i As Long

    AllTableNames = "Table_Dormant_Stock,Table_Overstock,Table_Negative_Stock,Table_Outdated_Stock_Counts,Table_Waste_Returns"
    TableNames = Split(AllTableNames, ",")

    For Each sh In wbTemplate.Worksheets
        For i = LBound(TableNames) To UBound(TableNames)
           sh.ListObjects(TableNames(i)).DataBodyRange.Font.Size = 10
        Next i
    Next sh
```

I get "Run-time Error "9": Subscript out of range".
I know it has something to do with the second loop, I've never done it before so not sure how to fix it.

Comment: Which line errors? Possibly you don't have a table with the name.

Comment: You're attempting to refresh **all** of those tables on **each** worksheet. Is there a copy of all 5 tables on every worksheet?

Comment: To add to @CLR's comment, table names have Workbook scope so you even if you had a copy on each sheet, the names would vary.

Comment: @BigBen - good point, and we now know why it errors so you need to check first whether the table exists or vary the list of tables according to the sheet.

Comment: @ SJR this line errors: "sh.ListObjects(TableNames(i)).DataBodyRange.Font.Size = 10"

Comment: @CLR each worksheet only has one table in it, which corresponds to the sheet name as well. All the tables do exist, I run a lot of other code on them.

Comment: @SimoneFick - if you follow our discussion you'll see that we have established the cause of the error.

Comment: If there's only one table on those sheets, then loop through those sheets only and modify the first table on them.

Comment: If there's only one table on each sheet you don't need the second loop at all. Just use the index.

Comment: `sh.ListObjects(1).DataBodyRange.Font.Size = 10`.

Comment: @SJR yes, the best answer. I'll upvote if you add it.

Comment: @BigBen - thanks, you're a gent!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one way of fixing your code:

```
For Each sh In wbTemplate.Worksheets
    For i = LBound(TableNames) To UBound(TableNames)

        For Each tbl In sh.ListObjects
            If tbl.Name = TableNames(i) Then
                tbl.DataBodyRange.Font.Size = 10
            End If
        Next tbl

    Next i
Next sh
```

So I've used your code to cycle through each sheet and each tablename in your array - but then instead of running the code on *that*, we check every table (`tbl`) on sheet `sh` and if the name matches the name you're looking for, ***then*** the code runs.

---

If you want to refresh any and all tables on each worksheet, then this is simple:

```
For Each sh In wbTemplate.Worksheets
    For Each tbl In sh.ListObjects
        tbl.DataBodyRange.Font.Size = 10
    Next
Next sh
```

Comment: This seems to be the best way to go since I have other sheets with tables on as well. I get a different error now:" '91' Object variable or With block variable not set." on the following line: " tbl.DataBodyRange.Font.Size = 10 "

Comment: Will it be easier to make a list of the Worksheet names and then just loop through those sheets and format any table on it?

Comment: Try adding a `Debug.print sh.Name, tbl.Name` line before the font size change so you can see which sheet and table it's getting stuck on.

Comment: I get a list with 3 of the 5 sheets.

Comment: @ CLR It got stuck on an empty table, so I just put in `On Error Resume Next` and it worked, thank you so much for all the help!

Comment: Rather than using `On Error..` you might be better off wrapping the font change code in a `If tbl.ListRows.Count > 0 Then ... <code> .. End If` to prevent the code attempting to run on an empty table.

Answer (score 1):

If you have only one table on each sheet, you can dispense with the second loop altogether and the array of names and just use the collection's index (1).

If you have other tables, use CLR's approach.

```
Sub x()

Dim wbTemplate As Workbook
Dim sh As Worksheet

For Each sh In wbTemplate.Worksheets
    sh.ListObjects(1).DataBodyRange.Font.Size = 10
Next sh

End Sub
```